# How to append a wget text file output to an exsisting file?

Tags: bash, shell, wget

I need to append a wget downloaded text file output to an existing file. I did this

```
wget https://fiddle.jshell.net/robots.txt -O text.txt
```

which creates a new file `text.txt` with content as

```
# See http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html for documentation on how to use the robots.txt file
```

But when I did

```
wget https://phpfiddle.org/robots.txt -O text.txt
```

The text file content is this

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /deposit/documents.php
Allow: /deposit/phpfiddle_apis.php
Allow: /deposit/phpfiddle_widgets.php
Allow: /deposit/widget001.php
Allow: /deposit/widget002.php
Allow: /deposit/widget003.php
Disallow: /deposit/
Sitemap: http://phpfiddle.org/sitemap.xml
```

were I expected it to be like this

```
# See http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html for documentation on how to use the robots.txt file
User-agent: *
Allow: /deposit/documents.php
Allow: /deposit/phpfiddle_apis.php
Allow: /deposit/phpfiddle_widgets.php
Allow: /deposit/widget001.php
Allow: /deposit/widget002.php
Allow: /deposit/widget003.php
Disallow: /deposit/
Sitemap: http://phpfiddle.org/sitemap.xml
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
wget 'https://fiddle.jshell.net/robots.txt' -O - > text.txt
wget 'https://phpfiddle.org/robots.txt' -O - >> text.txt
```

Note the `>>` on the 2nd one for "append".

Comment: For some reason this overwrites output file instead of appending in Windows 10 with wget 1.8.2. This is very strange, because `echo 1 >> out.txt` appends file and `wget http://some.com -O - 2>> out.txt` also appends file (not with downloaded file, but with download log). It looks like downloaded file contains some symbol, which prevents append function altogether.

Comment: A working workaround is `wget http://some.com -O ->out.txt` and then `type out.txt >> log.txt`